# Webpack and environment variable evaluation?

Tags: javascript, heroku, webpack, environment-variables

I am using webpack to bundle my front end app and load environment variables from heroku.

The environment variables can be parsed when its being used inside a function, but not when it's evaluated outside and assigned to a const :

```
import...

   /*This line will fail with : 'VM286683:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 
    0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)'*/
const geoApiSecretKey = JSON.parse(process.env.GEO_API_SECRET!);


function getGpsPosition() {

  //That one will parse the JSON without any issue
  const local_geoApiSecretKey = JSON.parse(process.env.GEO_API_SECRET!);
  ...
}
```

My webpack config loads the environment variables with the *DefinePlugin* :

```
...
plugins: [
        new CheckerPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template: 'index.html.ejs',}),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'GEO_API_SECRET': JSON.stringify(process.env.GEO_API_SECRET)
            }
        })
    ],
```

I guess its not related to webpack nor heroku. I am just missing something that I can't find here.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable was overriden in another file, thus changing its nature